# I have a span that should show the value of the indexMatch function, but it doesn't show what could be the error?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have my APPS SCRIPT function which does the following:

- Gets the active sheet ("EPP by function") and the data we need from it.
- Looks up the row index ("rowIndex") that corresponds to the provided lookup value ("lookupValue") in column "C" (which contains the lookup values).
- Looks up the column index ("col") that corresponds to the provided lookup column ("searchColumn") in row 3 (containing the column headers).
- Returns "IF expected for charge" if the value in the corresponding cell is "true", "NOT expected for charge" if the value in the corresponding cell is false ("false"), and "Missing data" or "Missing data" if the corresponding column or row is not found.

---

```
function indexMatch(columnaBusqueda, valorBusqueda) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("EPP por función");
  var data = sheet.getRange("D5:BW149").getValues();
  var lookup = sheet.getRange("C5:C149").getValues();
  var colIndex = sheet.getRange("D3:BX3").getValues()[0];
  var rowIndex = lookup.map(function(e) {return e[0];}).indexOf(valorBusqueda);
  if (rowIndex == -1) {
    return "Faltan datos";
  }
  var col = colIndex.indexOf(columnaBusqueda);
  if (col == -1) {
    return "Falta datos";
  }
  if (data[rowIndex][col] === true) {
    return "SI previsto para el cargo";
  } else if (data[rowIndex][col] === false) {
    return "NO previsto para el cargo";
  }
}
```

---

On the other hand, in my JAVASCRIPT code it only shows me "Missing data" despite the fact that in the ID input "cargo" and input "campo8" I enter matching values ​​and they should show me in the span message "YES planned for the charge".

```
  function adicionarProduto(dados) {
  //Crea el HTML del artículo para agregar al pedido
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("row");

  var divSelect = document.createElement("div");
  divSelect.classList.add("col-md-6");

  var labelSelect = document.createElement("label");
  labelSelect.textContent = dados[0].produto;

  var resultSpan = document.createElement("span");
  resultSpan.id = "result";
  resultSpan.style.color = "red";
  var resultado = ""; // Se declara la variable resultado

  var select = document.createElement("select");
  select.classList.add("form-select");
  select.id = "Campo8";

  dados.forEach((dado) => {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = dado.nome;
    select.appendChild(option);

    if (dado.nome === select.value) {
      valorG = dado.valorG;
    }

    if (dado.nome === select.value) {
      resultado = dado.resultado; // Se actualiza el valor de resultado
    }
  });

  resultSpan.textContent = resultado; // Se asigna el valor de resultado al elemento resultSpan

  //Agregar elementos a div
  divSelect.appendChild(labelSelect);
  divSelect.appendChild(resultSpan);
  divSelect.appendChild(select);

  //Crea el HTML de la cantidad del artículo para agregar al pedido
  var divQuantidade = document.createElement("div");
  divQuantidade.classList.add("col-md-2");

  var labelQuantidade = document.createElement("label");
  labelQuantidade.textContent = "Cantidad";

  var stockSpan = document.createElement("span");
  stockSpan.id = "stockSpan";
  stockSpan.textContent = " S:" + valorG;
  stockSpan.style.color = "red";

  //Agrega un EventListener al elemento select que actualiza el contenido del span cada vez que cambie su valor
  select.addEventListener("change", function () {
    var nome = this.value;
    var valor = 0;
    dados.forEach((dado) => {
      if (dado.nome == nome) valor = dado.valor;
    });
    valorG = dados.find((dado) => dado.nome === nome).valorG;
    stockSpan.textContent = " S:" + valorG;

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (resultado) {
      resultSpan.textContent = resultado;
    }).indexMatch(
      document.getElementById("cargo").value,
      document.getElementById("Campo8").value
    );

    var total = inpQuantidade.value * valor;
    inpValor.value = "S/" + total.toFixed(2);
    calculaTotal();
  });

var inpQuantidade = document.createElement("input");
inpQuantidade.type = "number";
inpQuantidade.value = 1;
inpQuantidade.classList.add("form-control");

//Agrega el OnChange Event Listener donde se actualizan los valores y llama a la función computeTotal
inpQuantidade.onchange = function () {
  let div = this.parentNode;
  var nome = div.parentNode.querySelector("select").value;
  var valor = 0;
  dados.forEach((dado) => {
    if (dado.nome == nome) valor = dado.valor;
  });
  var total = this.value * valor;
  div.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value = "S/" + total.toFixed(2);
  calculaTotal();
};

//Agregar elementos a div
divQuantidade.appendChild(labelQuantidade);
divQuantidade.appendChild(stockSpan);
divQuantidade.appendChild(inpQuantidade);

//Crea el HTML del valor del artículo para agregar al pedido
var divValor = document.createElement("div");
divValor.classList.add("col-md-3");

var labelValor = document.createElement("label");
labelValor.textContent = "Valor";

  var inpValor = document.createElement("input")
  inpValor.type = "text"
  inpValor.value = "S/"+dados[0].valor
  inpValor.classList.add("form-control")
  inpValor.classList.add("valor")

    //Agrega OnChange Event Listener donde llama a la función computeTotal
    inpValor.onchange = function(){
      calculaTotal()
    }

    //Agregar elementos a div
    divValor.appendChild(labelValor)
    divValor.appendChild(inpValor)

    //Crea el HTML del valor total del artículo para agregar al pedido
    var inpCusto = document.createElement("input")
    inpCusto.type = "number"
    inpCusto.value = dados[0].custo
    inpCusto.classList.add("custo")
    inpCusto.classList.add("displayNone")

    //Llama a la función que crea el HTML para eliminar el elemento si es necesario
    var divRemove = createDivRemove()

    //Agrega todos los divs creados al div principal del elemento
    div.appendChild(divSelect)
    div.appendChild(divQuantidade)
    div.appendChild(divValor)
    div.appendChild(inpCusto)
    div.appendChild(divRemove)

    var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container")
    containers[1].appendChild(div)
    containers[2].classList.remove("displayNone")
    
    calculaTotal()
  }
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <label>Cargo</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cargo" name="cargo" readonly>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome. The problem that you describe in your "javascript" is not clear and you don't provide an example of how and where the problem occurs and how it looks. Also you've not provided any data that could be used to reproduce your problem. Would you please provide more details about EXACTLY about the nature of your problem, and some sample data to reproduce it. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).